# This function in C# is returning data as 0 in excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, typescript

The function does not show errors, there are records in the database but they return an error:

```
public HttpFileModel ScheduledReport(ReportConfigurationModel reportConfiguration) {
    if (reportConfiguration == null) {
        throw new Exception("As configurações do relatório não foram informadas");
    }

    List<AttendanceCentral> attendanceCentrals = new List<AttendanceCentral>();
    List<int> attendanceCentralsIds = new List<int>();

    if (reportConfiguration.IdAttendanceCentrals.Count == 0) {
        attendanceCentrals = new List<AttendanceCentral> (attendanceCentralRepository.GetAllActive());
        attendanceCentrals.ForEach(x => attendanceCentralsIds.Add(x.Id.Value));
    } else {
        reportConfiguration.IdAttendanceCentrals.ForEach(x => attendanceCentrals.Add(attendanceCentralRepository.GetById(x)));
    }

    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = culture.DateTimeFormat;

    string attendanceNames = "";
    attendanceCentrals.ForEach(x => attendanceNames += x.Name.ToUpper() + " - ");
    attendanceNames = attendanceNames.Substring(0, attendanceNames.Length - 3);

    string citizenDataModel = "<div><p id='descricao'><b>Detalhamento dos Cidadões</b></p></div><table id='tabela'><thead><tr>";
    reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport.ForEach(x => citizenDataModel += ("<th class='celula_head'>" + Domain.TextValueFrom(x) + "</th>"));
    citizenDataModel += "</tr></thead><tbody>###DadosCidadaos###</tbody></table></tr>";

    string NewAttendanceCentral = "<h2 class='tituloCentral'>Central de Atendimento:<b>###CentralAtendimentoNome###</b></h2><div><p id='descricao'><b>Dados Relatório:</b></p></div></div><table id='tabela'><thead><tr><th class='celula_head'>Data</th><th class='celula_head'>Total Agendados</th></tr></thead><tbody>###DadosRelatorio###</tbody></table>";
    string ReportDataBase = "<tr><td class='celula_center'>###Data###</td><td class='celula_center'>###TotalAgendamentos###</td></tr>";

    string reportData = "";
    string dados = "";
    string htmlFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ApplicationConfiguration.TemplateDirectoryPath) + "\\reportBase.html";
    string htmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(htmlFile);

    ReportFilterModel reportFilterModel = new ReportFilterModel() {
        StartDate = reportConfiguration.StartDate,
        EndDate = reportConfiguration.EndDate,
        ListIdAttendanceCentrals = reportConfiguration.IdAttendanceCentrals.Count> 0 ? reportConfiguration.IdAttendanceCentrals : attendanceCentralsIds,
        VisualizationReportType = reportConfiguration.VisualizationReportType
    };

    string filterStartDate = reportConfiguration.VisualizationReportType == VisualizationReportType.Day ? reportFilterModel.StartDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyy") : (reportConfiguration.VisualizationReportType == VisualizationReportType.Month ? culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dtfi.GetMonthName(reportFilterModel.StartDate.Value.Month)) + " " + reportFilterModel.StartDate.Value.Year : reportFilterModel.StartDate.Value.Year.ToString());
    string filterEndDate = reportFilterModel.EndDate.HasValue ? (reportConfiguration.VisualizationReportType == VisualizationReportType.Day ? reportFilterModel.EndDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyy") : (reportConfiguration.VisualizationReportType == VisualizationReportType.Month ? culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dtfi.GetMonthName(reportFilterModel.EndDate.Value.Month)) + " " + reportFilterModel.EndDate.Value.Year : reportFilterModel.EndDate.Value.Year.ToString())) : "Data Atual";

    htmlString = htmlString.Replace("###NomeRelatorio###", "Relatório de Agendamentos");
    htmlString = htmlString.Replace("###Filtros###", "<br><b>Detalhamento do cidadão?</b>" + ((reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport != null && reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport.Count> 0) ? " Sim" : " Não")
             + "<br><b>Tipo visualização:</b> " + Domain.TextValueFrom(reportConfiguration.VisualizationReportType) + "<br><b>Data inicio:</b> " + filterStartDate + "<br><b>Data Fim:</b> " + filterEndDate + "<br><b>Centrais de Atendimento:</b> " + attendanceNames + "");
    htmlString = htmlString.Replace("###DataHora###", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));

    List<SchedulingItem> schedulings = schedulingItemRepository.GetNotAvailableSchedulesByDateAndAttendanceCentral(reportFilterModel);

    foreach(AttendanceCentral attendanceCentral in attendanceCentrals) {
        reportData = NewAttendanceCentral;
        reportData = reportData.Replace("###CentralAtendimentoNome###", attendanceCentral.Name.ToUpper());

        List<SchedulingItem> attendanceCentralSchedulingItems = schedulings.Where(x => x.AttendanceCentral != null ? x.AttendanceCentral.Id == attendanceCentral.Id : x.Scheduling.AttendanceCentral.Id == attendanceCentral.Id).ToList();

        DateTime currentDate = reportConfiguration.StartDate.HasValue ? reportConfiguration.StartDate.Value.Date : (attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.FirstOrDefault().DateScheduling.HasValue ? attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.FirstOrDefault().DateScheduling.Value.Date : attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.FirstOrDefault().HourReception.Value.Date);
        DateTime endDate = reportConfiguration.EndDate.HasValue ? reportConfiguration.EndDate.Value.Date : (attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.LastOrDefault().DateScheduling.HasValue ? attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.LastOrDefault().DateScheduling.Value.Date : attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.LastOrDefault().HourReception.Value.Date);

        if (reportConfiguration.VisualizationReportType == VisualizationReportType.Day) {
            while (currentDate.Date<= endDate) {
                List<SchedulingItem> attendanceCentralSchedulingItemsInDate = attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.Where(x => x.DateScheduling.Value.Date == currentDate.Date).ToList();

                int total = attendanceCentralSchedulingItemsInDate.Count;

                reportData += ReportDataBase;
                reportData = reportData.Replace("###Data###", currentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                reportData = reportData.Replace("###TotalAgendamentos###", total.ToString());

                currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
            }
        } else {
            if (reportConfiguration.VisualizationReportType == VisualizationReportType.Month) {
                while (currentDate.Date<= endDate.Date || (currentDate.Date> endDate.Date && currentDate.Month == endDate.Month)) {
                    List<SchedulingItem> attendanceCentralSchedulingItemsInDate = attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.Where(x => x.DateScheduling.Value.Month == currentDate.Month && x.DateScheduling.Value.Year == currentDate.Year).ToList();

                    int total = attendanceCentralSchedulingItemsInDate.Count;

                    reportData += ReportDataBase;
                    reportData = reportData.Replace("###Data###", culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dtfi.GetMonthName(currentDate.Month)) + " " + currentDate.Year);
                    reportData = reportData.Replace("###TotalAgendamentos###", total.ToString());

                    currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(1);
                }
            } else {
                while (currentDate.Year<= endDate.Year) {
                    List<SchedulingItem> attendanceCentralSchedulingItemsInDate = attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.Where(x => x.DateScheduling.Value.Year == currentDate.Year).ToList();

                    int total = attendanceCentralSchedulingItemsInDate.Count;

                    reportData += ReportDataBase;
                    reportData = reportData.Replace("###Data###", currentDate.Year + "");
                    reportData = reportData.Replace("###TotalAgendamentos###", total.ToString());

                    currentDate = currentDate.AddYears(1);
                }
            }
        }

        reportData += "<tr><td class='celula_head'>Total</td><td class='celula_head'>" + attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.Count.ToString() + "</tr>";
        reportData = reportData.Replace("###DadosRelatorio###", reportData);
        reportData += "<br>";

        dados += reportData + "<br>";
        reportData = "";

        if (reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport != null && reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport.Count> 0 && attendanceCentralSchedulingItems != null && attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.Count> 0) {

            string newCitizenDetail = "<div><p id='descricao'><b>Detalhamento do cidadão da central de atendimento:</b>###CentralAtendimentoNome###.</p></div><table id='tabela'><thead><tr>###CabecalhoDetalhamento###</tr></thead><tbody>###DadosRelatorioDetalhamento###</tbody></table>";

            var citizenData = "";
            citizenData += newCitizenDetail;
            citizenData = citizenData.Replace("###CentralAtendimentoNome###", attendanceCentral.Name.ToUpper());

            var detailHeader = "";
            var detailIndividualData = "<tr>";
            var citizenDetailGroup = "";

            foreach(var enumItem in reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport) {
                detailHeader += "<th class='celula_head'>" + Domain.TextValueFrom(enumItem) + "</th>";
                detailIndividualData += "<td class='celula_center'>###" + enumItem + "###</td>";
            }

            citizenData = citizenData.Replace("###CabecalhoDetalhamento###", detailHeader);

            attendanceCentralSchedulingItems = reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport.Any(x => x == FieldsCitizenReport.SchedulingDate) ? attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.OrderBy(x => x.DateScheduling.HasValue ? x.DateScheduling : x.HourReception).ToList() : attendanceCentralSchedulingItems.OrderBy(x => x.TemporaryCitizen.Name).ToList();

            foreach(var schedule in attendanceCentralSchedulingItems) {

                if (!reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport.Any(x => x == FieldsCitizenReport.SchedulingDate) && citizenDetailGroup.Contains(Convert.ToUInt64(schedule.TemporaryCitizen.CPF).ToString( @ "000\.000\.000\-00")))
                    continue;

                citizenDetailGroup += detailIndividualData;

                foreach(var item in reportConfiguration.FieldsCitizenReport) {
                    string infoInString = "";
                    Object itemInfo = null;
                    PropertyInfo properyInfo = null;

                    if (item != FieldsCitizenReport.SchedulingDate) {
                        properyInfo = schedule.TemporaryCitizen.GetType().GetProperty(item.ToString());

                        itemInfo = properyInfo.GetValue(schedule.TemporaryCitizen, null);
                    }

                    switch (item) {
                    case FieldsCitizenReport.Birthdate:
                        infoInString = itemInfo != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(itemInfo).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "";
                        break;

                    case FieldsCitizenReport.CNS:
                        infoInString = (itemInfo != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemInfo.ToString())) ? Convert.ToUInt64(itemInfo).ToString( @ "000\.0000\.0000\.0000") : "";
                        break;

                    case FieldsCitizenReport.CPF:
                        infoInString = (itemInfo != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemInfo.ToString())) ? Convert.ToUInt64(itemInfo).ToString( @ "000\.000\.000\-00") : "";
                        break;

                    case FieldsCitizenReport.SchedulingDate:
                        infoInString = schedule.DateScheduling.HasValue ? schedule.DateScheduling.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") : "Atendimento Espontâneo";
                        break;

                    case FieldsCitizenReport.Telephones:

                        Object telephoneObject = properyInfo.GetValue(schedule.TemporaryCitizen, null);
                        IList<Telephone> telephoneList = (IList<Telephone> )telephoneObject;

                        StringBuilder telephones = new StringBuilder();

                        telephoneList.ToList().ForEach(x => telephones.AppendLine(("(" + x.DDD + ")" + " " + x.Number)));

                        infoInString = telephones.ToString();
                        infoInString = infoInString.Length> 5 ? infoInString.Substring(0, infoInString.Length - 3) : infoInString;

                        break;

                    default:
                        infoInString = itemInfo != null ? itemInfo.ToString().ToUpper() : "";
                        break;
                    }

                    citizenDetailGroup = citizenDetailGroup.Replace("###" + item + "###", infoInString);
                }

                citizenDetailGroup += "</tr>";

            }
            citizenData = citizenData.Replace("###DadosRelatorioDetalhamento###", citizenDetailGroup);

            dados += citizenData;
        }
    }

    htmlString = htmlString.Replace("###Dados###", dados);

    htmlString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(htmlString, "&(?!(amp|apos|quot|lt|gt);)", "&amp;");

    try {
        HttpFileModel httpFileDto = new HttpFileModel() {
            FileName = "Comprovante de Agendamento.pdf",
            Content = fileManager.ConvertHtmlToPdf(htmlString, null, null, null),
            MimeType = "application/pdf"
        };

        return httpFileDto;
    } catch (Exception) {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao gerar o comprovante de veracidade");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to receive data from the bank, when I try through ScheduleAPI, it tells me the error on the line:

```
 attendanceCentrals.ForEach(x => attendanceNames += x.Name.ToUpper() + " - ");
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code you've posted is quite complex, and it's difficult to pinpoint the error without knowing what the actual error message says or without having access to all the dependencies and database schema.